# remove custom object from array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table with Gift Cards 
1,2,3 .... 100 $ Gift card
user tel me I want 123$

### I tell him based on his request, which card he must use

I have this array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Card_1] => 20 $
        [Card_2] => 50 $
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Card_1] => 50 $
        [Card_2] => 20 $
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Card_1] => 40 $
        [Card_2] => 50 $
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Card_1] => 50 $
        [Card_2] => 40 $
    )
)
```

and I have this function

```
function DeleteDup ($allcard){
    foreach ($allcard as $key => $all) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count ($allcard); $i++) {

            $new = array();
            $new["Card_1"] = $allcard[$i]["Card_2"];
            $new["Card_2"] = $all["Card_1"];

            if($new == $all){
                unset($allcard[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $allcard;
}
```

I want to keep one of these two items

```
[2] => Array
    (
        [Card_1] => 40 $
        [Card_2] => 50 $
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Card_1] => 50 $
        [Card_2] => 40 $
    )
```

and delete one of them

please help me

I tested everything

it's two different key but equal at a different position

Comment: you can just `unset($array[$index])` and you will remove `$index` in `$array` (ex. `unset($allcard[0]); unset($allcard[1]);` and you got your result)

Comment: there are not equal
allcard[0] = ["card_1" => 50 , "card_2" => 40]
allcard[1] = ["card_1" => 40, "card_2" => 50]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are trying to filter out the array that does not contains 40 or 50 as their value.

You could use the [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to do that :

This function takes an array as the first argument and a callback as the second. It will parse every element of the array and if the current element passes the condition in the callback, it will be pushed into a new array, that will be returned by the function.

```
$array = [...]
$filteredArray = array_filter($array, function($item) {
    // if the item passes this condition, it will in the filteredArray
    return in_array($item['Card_1'], ['40 $', '50 $']) && in_array($item['Card_2'], ['40 $', '50 $'])
});
```

Here I'm using the function `in_array` because I did not want to do 4 checks. 
You could change the condition however you like, the base concept stays the same

**P.S.** This code is untested, please don't just copy and paste it expecting everything to work. Try to understand what i've done and apply this concept to your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep only one entry where the sum of the values are the same, try this:

```
$sums   = array_map('array_sum', $allcard);
$uniq   = array_unique($sums);
$result = array_diff_key($allcard, $uniq);
```

- Sum the numbers in each array
- Get only unique sum values
- Compute the difference in the keys to get only the unique ones

One-liner:

```
$result = array_diff_key($allcard, array_unique(array_map('array_sum', $allcard)));
```

This will work with numeric values or ones like `50 $` that will be cast to the correct numeric value.  It will not work for things like `$50` as it will be cast to `0`.

---

Since you may have (`50` and `40`) and (`60` and `30`) which have the same sum, this may not be what you want.  This compares the actual values:

```
$sorted = array_map(function($v) { sort($v); return $v; }, $allcard);
$result = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', $sorted)));
```

- Sort each sub-array so that they will have the same serialized value
- Serialize each sub-array to a string and get unique values
- Unserialize each sub-array

One-liner:

```
$result  = array_map('unserialize', array_unique(array_map('serialize', array_map(
                     function($v) {
                         sort($v); return $v;
                     }, $allcard))));
```

Comment: thanks, it's a good method but I have an array with 50,50 values, this will remove it too

Comment: Just thought of that and added another solution.

Comment: I did it in a simple way, I sent the code on this post

Answer (score 0):

Final Code is:

```
$sums = array_map ( 'array_sum' , $allcard );
$uniq = array_unique ( $sums );
$result = array_diff_key ( $allcard , $uniq );

foreach ($allcard as $key => $all) {
    if ($all["Card_1"] == $all["Card_2"]) {
        array_push ( $result , $all );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you add information about what you did, it might help others in the same situation as you.